# How to add newline within one radio button control in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, newline, radiobuttonlist

**UPDATE: (working code attached)**
I remove the NewLine / Environment.NewLine, and replaced them by adding `<br/>` in the ***`"Session :"`***, 
which meant by ***`"<br/> Session :"`***, worked like a charm! Thanks @nelek

```
With rdlSession.Items
  .Add("Session :" + session.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + _
  "Date :" + day.ToString() + vbNewLine + _
  "Coach :" + coach.ToString() + vbNewLine + _
  "Available slot :" + slot.ToString())
End With
```

How to arrange them into four rows instead of bulking up within one row?

They are one of my options in radiobuttonlist. I have tried using **Environment.Newline** , **vbNewline** , **NewLine**.

Is there any possible way to make it?

[image: Click here to see image]

Comment: Are you using forms or web forms?

Comment: @Blackwood It doesn't need one. It always supports wrapping, so long as you have `AutoSize` turned off. Still waiting to hear if this fellow is using WinForms, WebForms, or what, though.

Comment: I'm using web forms @Son_of_Sam

Comment: try using `<br>` instead `vbNewLine` and so on... example : `rdlSession.Items.Add("Session : " + session.ToString() + "<br> Date : " + day.ToString() + "<br>Coach : " + coach.ToString() + "<br>Available slot : "+slot.ToString())`.

Comment: @nelek It worked by then! :) Any idea why NewLine / Environment.NewLine cant helps doing it?

Comment: Not sure, but looking in Page Source I can see, if You using `Environment.NewLine` You'll get, well, new line :)) ... like You wrote pure html... if You wrote, for example : `some word` and press `Enter` and wrote `some other word` You'll get in two lines (but only in editor)... html would show in single line... so, instead new line I always use `<br>` (expect textbox).

Comment: @nelek Great m8! Should have think out of the box! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: (working code attached)**
I remove the NewLine / Environment.NewLine, and replaced them by adding `<br/>` in the `"Session :"`, 
which meant by `"<br/> Session :"` and it worked like a charm! Thanks @nelek